# Could Not parse java.lang.NumberFormat Exception

Tags: android, parsing, int

```
try{    
    if (flag_conv == false)
    {
      if ((Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()))<=55)
      {
       final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
       alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
       alertDialog.setMessage("WB should be grater than 55");

       alertDialog.setButton2("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
          {
                // here you can add functions
                dialog.dismiss();
          }});
       alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
       alertDialog.show();
       tv1.setText("WB");
       et1.setText("");
       wbflg = true;
       wbval = 0;
       return;          
     }
     else
     {                     
      wbval = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
     }
   }
 catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);}
```

And i got the following Exception

```
07-31 14:48:45.409: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:50.569: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:54.599: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:54.829: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:54.958: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:55.108: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:55.259: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:48:55.409: DEBUG/dalvikvm(118): GREF has increased to 201
07-31 14:48:55.429: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
07-31 14:52:43.798: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [small project in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377469/small-project-in-android)

Comment: Have you read the exception? It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 8):

#### On `Integer.parseInt`

The exception message seems to be the following:

```
07-31 14:48:45.409: INFO/System.out(431): Could not parse
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

Indeed, an empty string can not be parsed by [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). Thus:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("");
// throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

If you have an arbitrary `String s` which can be [`isEmpty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) or even `null`, then you must have special code to handle it, because `Integer.parseInt(s)` will always throw an exception in those cases.

Of course `Integer.parseInt(s)` can throw [`NumberFormatException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) when `s` is e.g. `"xyz"`, so you may want to put the statement inside a `try-catch` block.

So you can write something like this:

```
String s = ...;
if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
   complaintAboutNotGettingAnything();
} else {
   try {
     int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
     doSomethingWith(num);
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     complaintAboutGettingSomethingYouDontWant();
   }
}
```

---

#### On writing code that is easy to debug

In this particular snippet, it looks like `parseInt` is invoked as follows:

```
if ((Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()))<=55) ...
```

A lot of things can go wrong in this one expression. I suggest refactoring that breaks this apart into logical observable steps as follows:

```
String et1text = et1.getText().toString();
// maybe check if it's empty/null if necessary
// maybe log/inspect what the value of et1text is for debugging

try {
   int et1val = Integer.parseInt(et1text);
   if (et1val <= THRESHOLD) {
      // ...
   }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   moreComplaining();
}
```

Comment: Above and beyond the call of duty.  Nice

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Java but if you have strings which might not be valid ints
you may have a function like in C# of:

```
bool res = Int.TryParse(s,ref int);
```