# How to Apply the Textchange event on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I developed one simple app, like subtraction, addition.
In this app I use three EditTexts, one for answer and other two for question.
I want to calculate the answer of question on text change event. But when I apply the text change event on both of this the event occur but not properly work. Because when I enter in the text in first EditText of question the event occur but it throws this exception:

```
07-03 16:39:48.844: E/EduApp Log :=>(12537): Error In Text change Event java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

What do I do?
I use the `TextWatcher` for text change event.

```
txtOne.addTextChangedListener(this);
txtTwo.addTextChangedListener(this);

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think you are receiving empty String `" "` which is causing this problem. Make sure you get a non-empty String from your `EditText`.

Consider your `EditText` doesn't have any value typed in, and you are trying to get its value and convert into int you will run into this kind of problem.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
            if(!s.equals("") ) { 
                //do your work here 
            }
    }



    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Also check this link for more idea,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377648/603744

Comment: Try this - if(!s.equals('')) , Since we are getting CharSequence

Comment: Use StringUtils.isEmpty rather than s.equals(""). Much more efficient.

Comment: To me s never equals to an empty string ("").

Answer (score 2):

i think the best in case the edittext type is number... use the (length function) of parameter
 instead of (equle() function) 
ex:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (s.length() > 0)
                { //do your work here }
        }

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it's correct:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    String inputs = input.getText().toString();
    Integer index=0;
    if(!inputs.equals("")) 
        index=Integer.valueOf(inputs);

}
```

Comment: doesn't look different from the other answer, does it ;-) And will still throw a ParseException if the field content isn't ... parseable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your editText value is empty or not first. Something like this:

```
String textValue;
textValue = edittext().getText().toString());
Log.v("","Value is " + textValue);
if(textValue != ""){
   // Call Text Change Listener Here
}else{
   // Throw error message or something
}
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: what's the log cat say then ?

Answer (score 0):

Added **Kotlin** implementation for future reference

```
 webUrl.editText!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                var urlToload: String
                if (s ==null || s.isEmpty()) {
                    urlToload = UniversalWebViewFragment.YOUTUBE_SERACH_URL + "hd trailers"
                } else {
                    urlToload = UniversalWebViewFragment.GOOGLE_SERACH_URL + s.toString()
                }

                loadURL(urlToload)
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was solved with these 2 actions:
1 - **android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"**  (it did not solve the problem itself)
2 - adding the listener:

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

                Log.e("JFT", "EDITTEXT => = "+s);
                if(!s.equals("") ) {
                    //do your work here
                }
            }



            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Kotlin use this below code

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
   override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
       if (edit1.text.toString().length == 1) {
             edit2.requestFocus()
       }
   }

   override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int
   ) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
})
```