# How to show a "Clear button" after the first character pressed and hide it when the text is ""?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I need to show a clear button at the right of an edit text and hide it when the text is"". How can I do that.

I just need to know how to show and hide it when the text length>0 or =0, nothing more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/counting-chars-in-edittext-changed-listener)

Comment: have a look at this http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/04/android-edittext-with-cross-button-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

     @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

     @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
       int count, int after) {
      }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
       int before, int count) {
       if(s.length() != 0)
        // set the visibility
    }
     });
```

Comment: @andri : didi u ck this

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309734/5432730) is your answer.

Use code and make button visibility on and off on textchange by check character length.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at below code, it may help you :

```
EditText etSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String str = etSearch.getText().toString();
                if (str.isEmpty()) {
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Text-watcher may work for you

```
If(editText1.getText.toString.length>0)
 {
  if(button1.getVisibility == View.GONE)
  {
  button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
  }
}
else
{
 if(button1.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE)
  {
  button1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set It's Visibility GONE from xml.**

```
If(editText1.getText.toString.length>0)
 {
  if(button1.getVisibility == View.GONE)
  {
  button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
   }
}
else
{
 if(button1.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE)
  {
  button1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why GONE and not INVISIBLE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TextWatcher`, a type of Listener:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        //Here, you can check for text size...
        int length = editText.toString().length();
         [...]



      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}

}
```

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener).